# How can I create save file without temporary file with AngularJS / Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, electron

How can I create a save file without a temporary file?

When I click on my "Export" button, I get a window that gives me the choice for a destination of my save file, but I have a temporary file :

`~/Downloads/.org.chromium.Chromium.XXXXXX`

```
// Export project
    $scope.exportProject = function () {
         var blob  = new Blob(['content_config'], {type: 'text/json'}),
                 event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
                 file  = document.createElement('a');

             // Name file
             file.download = 'my_config';

             // Create link
             file.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             file.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', file.download, file.href].join(':');

             // Init event
             event.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

             // Dispatch event
             file.dispatchEvent(event);
    };
```

The application accesses the following location(s):

`~/Downloads/.org.chromium.Chromium.XXXXXX` because there is a temporary file.

How can I don't use a temporary file when I click on "Export" button, call my function?